# How do I get my API to include a child class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web API that returns Events:

**Non relevant portions omitted for brevity**

**EventController.cs**

```
namespace HobbsEventsMobile.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/event
        [HttpGet]
        public List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> Get()
        {
            return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();
        }
}
```

This makes a call to:

**Event.cs**

```
namespace HobbsEventsMobile.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public int ID;
        public DateTime DateBegin;
        public DateTime DateEnd;
        public DateTime TimeBegin;
        public int Duration;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
        public Category Category;
        public string Location;

        public Event()
        {

        }

        public static  List<Event> GetEventSummary()  //List<Event> GetEventSummary()
        {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            DataTable thisDT = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string SprocName = "HE_GetEventSummary";
                SqlDataAdapter thisAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SprocName, connection);
                thisAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                thisAdapter.Fill(thisDT);
            }

            foreach(DataRow row in thisDT.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventDateBegin"]) >= DateTime.Today)
                {
                    Event myEvent = new Event();
                    myEvent.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["EventID"]);
                    myEvent.DateBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventDateBegin"].ToString());
                    myEvent.DateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventDateEnd"]);
                    myEvent.TimeBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["EventTimeBegin"]);
                    myEvent.Duration = Convert.ToInt32(row["Duration"]);
                    myEvent.Name = row["EventName"].ToString();
                    myEvent.Description = row["EventDesc"].ToString();
                    myEvent.Category = Category.Find(Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]));
                    myEvent.Location = row["Location"].ToString();

                    events.Add(myEvent);
                }
            }

            return events;
        }
    }
}
```

Which has a child class:

**Category.cs**

```
namespace HobbsEventsMobile.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;

        public static List<Category> GetEventCategories()
        {
            List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
            DataTable thisDT = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string SprocName = "HE_GetEventCategories";
                SqlDataAdapter thisAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SprocName, connection);
                thisAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                thisAdapter.Fill(thisDT);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in thisDT.Rows)
            {
                categories.Add(new Category(Convert.ToInt32(row["Category"]), row["CategoryName"].ToString()));
            }

            return categories;
        }

        public static Category Find(int id)
        {
            List<Category> categories = Category.GetEventCategories();
            return categories.First(c => c.ID == id);
        }

        public Category(int id, string name)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the issue: before I added `[DataContract]` to `Category`, I was getting this error:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
    Type 'HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Category' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

Now the error is gone, but it's not actually returning any categories:

```
<Event>
<Category/>
<DateBegin>2014-05-23T00:00:00</DateBegin>
<DateEnd>2014-05-23T00:00:00</DateEnd>
<Description>
Bring your blanket or lawn chairs and enjoy a free showing of Disney's Monster's University. Movie will begin at dusk with parking on the East side of the pool. 397-9291 for more information.
</Description>
<Duration>210</Duration>
<ID>2081</ID>
<Location>Del Norte Park/Pool</Location>
<Name>Movies Under the Stars</Name>
<TimeBegin>2014-05-23T19:30:00</TimeBegin>
</Event>
```

**What gives?**

---

**Update 1**

To answer a comment, yes, I have done some debugging. I created a view just for this:

**from ApplicationController.cs**

```
public ActionResult CategoryTest()
{
    ViewBag.Events = Event.GetEventSummary();
    return View();
}
```

**CategoryTest.cshtml**

```
<h2>CategoryTest</h2>
@{
    foreach (HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event thisEvent in ViewBag.Events)
    {
        <li>@thisEvent.Name @thisEvent.Category.Name</li>
    }
}]
```

**The output:**

[image]

Comment: Do you know for sure that you are getting a non-null `Category` back for your objects? In other words, have you debugged this?

Comment: null `Category` is not possible without exception, as OP is calling categories.First in static Category.Find method

Comment: @SvenGrosen Yes. Just added an update that shows this.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `[DataMember]` on the `[DataContract]` variables? As far as I know, it won't serialize variables if they aren't marked as datamembers.

Comment: Just a guess, but try marking event with `[DataContract]` and its Category property with `[DataMember]`.

Comment: You do not need DataContract/DataMember attributes defined. The framework should take care of this...

Comment: @deoatroll I mentioned in my question that I was hitting an error without it. Please refer to that.

Comment: @anwyatt I am interested in understanding how to recreate your problem. Is there any way you can mock this setup; recreate the error, and share that code. We can defer this to a chat room and perhaps take things from there if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, I'll give an example.

I think you want:

```
namespace HobbsEventsMobile.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Category
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name;
        // everything else
    }
}
```

When you serialize the class, it should now serialize the variables as well. As your code stands, it's just serializing the class with nothing in it.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! You can also specify a fair few other properties on datamembers, as well as datacontracts.

Here's some links to the MSDN articles :) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx